# How to get local eslint plugins to work with locally installed eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

According to the docs plugins should work if they are npm modules named "eslint-plugin-"

[Here's a plugin that follows that pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-require). [Source is here](https://github.com/bregenspan/eslint-plugin-require).

So, we make a new project

```
md foo
cd foo
npm init
... answer questions ..
npm install --save-dev eslint
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-require
echo "define(function(){});" > test.js
echo "{\"rules\":{\"require\": 2}}" > conf.json
node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -c conf.json --plugin eslint-plugin-require test.js
```

produces

```
~/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint.js:569
                throw new Error("Definition for rule '" + key + "' was not
                      ^
Error: Definition for rule 'require' was not found.
```

change the config to

```
echo "{\"rules\":{\"eslint-plugin-require\": 2}}" > conf.json
```

nor

```
echo "{\"rules\":{\"require-define\": 2}}" > conf.json
```

nor

```
echo "{\"rules\":{\"require-require-define\": 2}}" > conf.json
```

nor

```
echo "{\"rules\":{\"eslint-plugin-require-define\": 2}}" > conf.json
```

nor

```
echo "{\"rules\":{\"eslint-plugin-require-require-define\": 2}}" > conf.json
```

does not fix it

How do I use locally installed eslint plugins?

Comment: If you use console eslint, plugins should be installed globally

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is fairly simple to use local plugins with a local eslint install, just not immediately obvious at first.

**1. Install**

Nothing different here from what you're already doing.

```
npm install --save-dev eslint
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-require
```

**2. Configure**

I'm using a `.eslintrc` file in my case, but the same principle should apply if you're passing a custom config file to the CLI. Note the difference in how rules are defined when it's a plugin.

```
{
    "plugins": [
        // Tell eslint about the require plugin
        "require"
    ],
    "rules": {
        // Built-in Rules
        "camelcase": 2,
        "no-trailing-spaces": 2,

        // Require Plugin Rules (note plugin prefix)
        "require/require-define": 2,
        "require/require-array-syntax": 2,
        "require/require-module-prefix": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: then run which cmd on the CLI? I run `eslint` in current project folder, but it's not recognized as a command.

Comment: @Felix - it'll be in your node_modules/.bin folder, so running `./node_modules/.bin/eslint` should do the trick.